# My manager is not delegating tasks

Tags: manager, time-management, task-management

My manager and I are meant to have weekly catch-ups when she assigns me tasks and responsibilities. However, for the last 6 months she has been very busy and thus we don't have regular catch-ups anymore.  I also see her doing tasks that I could be doing instead.

I tried raising the issue, to which she agrees and says that we should have a catch-up after which she proceeds to miss the agreed upon date.

As a result I have very little work to do. However when I try to take on other projects she steps in and says I don't have time to do so.

How can I help her delegate work to me?

Comment: When you say you are trying to 'take on other projects' and she steps in, are these things that are on your manager's backlog or completely separate from her responsibilities?

Comment: @kozaky I have tried both. Some were separate others on the backlog. With those on the backlog she typically tells me that the projects are less important. However the more important projects are done from my perspective and awaiting her input/feedback

Comment: Have you told her that you don't have enough work to do? What did she say / do?

Comment: @dukeling don't think I have said do directly but I have asked things like "is there anything else I can do? Is there something I can help with?" Do u think I should just ask for more work ?

Answer (score 3):

> What should I do?

You should continue to set up meetings with your manager to discuss what tasks you should be handling.  In the meantime when you see your manager doing tasks you should be doing, approach them and say:

"*Hey, I know you're really busy; let me handle this for you.*"

When you complete the task, *let them know its done*.  This may help them let go of the task and **trust it will get done**.

Keep doing this and hopefully your manager will realize they have a resource with some bandwidth.  If not, it may be time to get another job.